# ERPNext: How can I generate user session without Password?

Tags: authentication, session, password-encryption, erpnext

As an ERPNext fresher, I am creating a `REST API` for the mobile app, where the use case is, the Mobile user will send a request to do login using **Face authentication**, as a result of **Face authentication** at the mobile end, it will return `User ID`(same as ERPNext UserID).

As a Param, I will get `UserID` and other params of `API request`, here in response, I have to send a new `session` generated for that `User`.

***Applied solution:***

- Tried Login by fetching password of user based on `UserID`, which basically gives encryption error for encrypted password.
- Tried bypass `login` and generate new `session`, failed due to password not being added
- Decrypt the password to use as param for new `session`

My current problem is, I don't have `Password` in normal format, and need to generate a valid user session, for the next operation post `face recognization`(face validation is already done through SDK).

Answer (score 0):

You can use token based authentication for REST Api, based on your question when you receive emailid (same as erpnext user id),  you can identify the user and generate api_key and api_secret, you can return these keys in response to your request, also you can store these secrets keys and use for future requests to authenticate it

You can refer docs here https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/api/rest#1-token-based-authentication

Below is sample code, please note code is not tested, posted just for reference

```
@frappe.whitelist(allow_guest=True)
def validate_user(email):
user_email = frappe.db.get_all('User', filters={'name': email}, fields=['name'])
user = frappe.get_doc('User', user_email[0]['name'])

api_generate = generate_keys(user.name)
user_resp = frappe.get_doc('User', user.name)

frappe.response["message"] = {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Authentication success",
    "api_key": user_resp.api_key,
    "api_secret": api_generate,
    "username": user.username,
    "email": user_resp.email,
    "role": user_resp.roles[0].role
    }


def generate_keys(user):
user_details = frappe.get_doc('User', user)
api_secret = frappe.generate_hash(length=15)

if not user_details.api_key:
    api_key = frappe.generate_hash(length=15)
    user_details.api_key = api_key

frappe.db.set_value('User', user, 'api_secret', api_secret)

return api_secret
```

Comment: How you will revoke the api_key and api_secret if it has compromised?

Comment: @pepe you can call generate_keys() function